# spring boot and spring batch throw NullPointerException in DAO of ItemProcessor batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am having problems in my spring boot and spring batch application , I share my situation have my layer Dao which is a interface is throwning NPE (`NullPointerException`) and it implemented, it had annotation `@Autowired` and I did test with Junit for check it and works but I don´t know that´s wrong in my configuration job or CustomItemProccesor, here is my code, I hope you can help me, please, thanks.

Config Job:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.company.batch.config","com.company.batch.dao","com.company.batch.mapper","com.company.batch.model","com.company.batch.particion","com.company.batch.procesos","com.company.batch.reader","com.company.batch.writers"})
public class ConfigJob 
{

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sqlserverDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Bean(name = "demoPartitionStep")
    public Step step1Manager(Step slaveStep) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1.manager")
            .<String, String>partitioner("step1", demoPartitioner())
            .step(slaveStep)
            .gridSize(numerohilos())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "demoPartitioner", destroyMethod = "")
    public Partitioner demoPartitioner() {
        RangePartitioner partitioner = new RangePartitioner();
        //partitioner.setDataSource(dataSource);
        // partitioner.partition(20);
        return partitioner;
    }

    // slave step
    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep(ItemReader<beangenerico> demoReader)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
                .chunk(1)
                //.reader(pagingItemReader(null, null))
                .reader(demoReader)
                .processor(compositeProcessor())
                .writer(new ListDelegateWriter())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public CompositeItemProcessor compositeProcessor() {
        List<ItemProcessor> delegates = new ArrayList<>(3);
        delegates.add(new CustomerItemProcessor());
        delegates.add(new AccountsItemProcessor());
        delegates.add(new beanDataItemProccesor());

        CompositeItemProcessor processor = new CompositeItemProcessor();

        processor.setDelegates(delegates);

        return processor;
    }


    @Bean(name = "demoWriter")
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter< beangenerico> CustomItemWriter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CustomItemWriter wri = new CustomItemWriter();
        return wri;
    }


    @Bean(name = "demoReader")
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<beangenerico> formiikreader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fromId']}") int minValue,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['toId']}") int maxValue){
        myReader fr = new myReader(minValue,maxValue);
        return fr;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(@Qualifier("demoPartitionStep") Step demoPartitionStep) {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(demoPartitionStep)
                .build();
    }

}
```

This is the CustomerItemProcessor of spring batch

```
@Component
public class CustomerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<beangenerico,ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>> {
 {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    private ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> listbean = new ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>();

    public ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> process(beangenerico rangos) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("entro a customitemprocessor");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            listbean.set(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>());

            System.out.println("rangos:"+rangos.getIni()+"-"+rangos.getFin()); //si trae datos
            listbean = customerDAO.getAccAgentes(rangos);

            if(listbean != null) {
                return listbean;
            } else {
                return null;
            }

    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerDAO(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
        this.customerDAO = customerDAO;
    }

}
```

Here is my interface Dao

```
public interface CustomerDAO {
    ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> getAccAgentes(beangenerico bean);
}
```

This is the DAO implementation:

```
@Repository("customerDAO")
public class CustomerDAOImpl  implements CustomerDAO{ 

    private String SP_SQL = "{call mysp(?, ?)}";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sqlserverDataSource")
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> customerList2=new ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>();
    private beanCustomer b = null; 


    public  ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> getAccAgentes(beangenerico bean) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                customerList2.set(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>());
                System.out.println("entro a metodo");
                if(getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource()!=null) {
                    System.out.println("success con"); //with junit test is ok
                }else {
                    System.out.println("null conn");
                }
                return getJdbcTemplate().query(
                        SP_SQL,
                        new Object [] {bean.getIni(),bean.getFin()}, new ResultSetExtractor<ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>>() {    

                            @Override
                            public ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> extractData(ResultSet rs)
                                    throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                while(rs.next()){
                                b = new beanCustomer();
                                b.setIduser(rs.getString("iduser_co"));
                                b.setAccount(rs.getString("account_co"));
                                b.setTypeUser(rs.getString("type_idag"));
                                customerList2.get().add(b);
                                }
                                return customerList2;
                            }
                        });
            }catch(Exception e) {}

            System.out.println("size lista: "+customerList2.get().size());
            return customerList2;

    }

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        if (null == jdbcTemplate) {
            jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }   

}
```

Stack trace:

```
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
entro a customitemprocessor
rangos:71-80
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=1, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Rollback for RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.company.batch.procesos.CustomerItemProcessor.process(CustomerItemProcessor.java:69)
    at com.company.batch.procesos.CustomerItemProcessor.process(CustomerItemProcessor.java:1)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor.processItem(CompositeItemProcessor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor.process(CompositeItemProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:210)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Initiating transaction rollback
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Rolling back resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@1337e94]
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Handling exception: java.lang.NullPointerException, caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Handling fatal exception explicitly (rethrowing first of 1): java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2020-04-28 11:15:03 - Encountered an error executing step slaveStep in job job
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.company.batch.procesos.CustomerItemProcessor.process(CustomerItemProcessor.java:69)
    at com.company.batch.procesos.CustomerItemProcessor.process(CustomerItemProcessor.java:1)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor.processItem(CompositeItemProcessor.java:63)
```

here

```
listbean = customerDAO.getAccAgentes(rangos);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem is that was not instancing the bean in the Config , here put my solution in the code ConfigJob , hoping that help someone else.

```
@ComponentScan({"com.company.batch.config","com.company.batch.dao","com.company.batch.mapper","com.company.batch.model","com.company.batch.particion","com.company.batch.procesos","com.company.batch.reader","com.company.batch.writers"})
public class ConfigJob 
{

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sqlserverDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Bean(name = "demoPartitionStep")
    public Step step1Manager(Step slaveStep) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1.manager")
            .<String, String>partitioner("step1", demoPartitioner())
            .step(slaveStep)
            .gridSize(numerohilos())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "demoPartitioner", destroyMethod = "")
    public Partitioner demoPartitioner() {
        RangePartitioner partitioner = new RangePartitioner();
        //partitioner.setDataSource(dataSource);
        // partitioner.partition(20);
        return partitioner;
    }

    // slave step
    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep(ItemReader<beangenerico> demoReader)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
                .chunk(1)
                //.reader(pagingItemReader(null, null))
                .reader(demoReader)
                .processor(compositeProcessor())
                .writer(new ListDelegateWriter())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public CompositeItemProcessor compositeProcessor() {
        List<ItemProcessor> delegates = new ArrayList<>(3);
        delegates.add(new CustomerItemProcessor());
        delegates.add(new AccountsItemProcessor());
        delegates.add(new beanDataItemProccesor());

        CompositeItemProcessor processor = new CompositeItemProcessor();

        processor.setDelegates(delegates);

        return processor;
    }

     @Bean
    public CustomerItemProcessor CustomerProccesor(){
        return new CustomerItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountsItemProcessor AccountsItemProcessor(){
        return new AccountsItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public beanDataItemProccesor beanDataItemProccesor(){
        return new beanDataItemProccesor();
    }

    @Bean(name = "demoWriter")
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter< beangenerico> CustomItemWriter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CustomItemWriter wri = new CustomItemWriter();
        return wri;
    }


    @Bean(name = "demoReader")
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<beangenerico> formiikreader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fromId']}") int minValue,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['toId']}") int maxValue){
        myReader fr = new myReader(minValue,maxValue);
        return fr;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(@Qualifier("demoPartitionStep") Step demoPartitionStep) {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(demoPartitionStep)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When defining `CompositeItemProcessor` , you are creating `CustomerItemProcessor` by yourself which cause its dependent beans cannot be injected and resulting NPE. You should get the `CustomerItemProcessor` from the Spring context rather than creating it by yourself. Something like:

```java
    @Bean
    public CompositeItemProcessor compositeProcessor(CustomerItemProcessor customerItemProcessor) {
        List<ItemProcessor> delegates = new ArrayList<>(3);
        delegates.add(customerItemProcessor);

        CompositeItemProcessor processor = new CompositeItemProcessor();

        processor.setDelegates(delegates);

        return processor;
    }
```

The same applies to other delegated beans of the `CompositeItemProcessor` such as `AccountsItemProcessor` etc.